# Ошибка открытия сайта

Tags: windows-10, браузер

Встретил такую ошибку впервые. Гугление ничего не даёт.

> The browser you are using may have difficulty receiving images and video. If you experience any issues viewing this page, we suggest using Internet Explorer, Mozilla Firefox, or Apple Safari.

Что это за феномен?

Машина на которой пытаюсь открыть сайт не работала более полугода. За это время на сайте обновился сертификат. И замок горит красным. Сертификат от [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). Ставили и удаляли **КриптоПро**.
[image: Ошибка при открытия сайта]

Comment: Дайте ссылку, чтобы посмотреть.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev у вас он откроется. Это проблема на пользаке.

Comment: @doox911 в другом браузере работает?

Comment: @Dizzy221 ни на одном. Скачивал новые и обновлял старые.

Comment: Попробуйте через 3G, другую сеть

Comment: @StrangerintheQ А что это может проверить?

Comment: @doox911 роутер например, или что там у вас

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Вы думает проблема с сетью? Но почему все остальные сайты открываются?

Comment: @doox911 меня гугл отправил на форум dlink...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88419/discussion-between-doox911-and-stranger-in-the-q).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что в файле **/etc/hosts**`(linux)` был прописан не верный **ip**. Т.е. доменное имя не принадлежало этому **ip**. А эта ошибка выводится сервером, который располагается по этому **ip**.